# What is mapping in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I read few pages and regarding mapping in ElasticSearch.org and other blogs, But I am not able to clear what exactly mean of mapping in ES, can you please compare with any SQL language which concept matches with mapping in ES.

Please clear me please.

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch needs to know what type of data each field contains. The information is called mapping in elastic search.

Its similar to data types, we specify the data type of a variable so the compiler knows what type of data gets store, Int, string, float and takes the necessary actions associated with a type. In traditional Databases we define the column types for each column field.

Read this to understand [what is a Document?](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/document.html) , Then read the definition of mapping below.

"Each document in an index has a type. Every type has its own mapping or schema definition. A mapping defines the fields within a type, the datatype for each field, and how the field should be handled by Elasticsearch. A mapping is also used to configure metadata associated with the type."

Answer (score 0):

When you create a table, you need to define what each field is.

A mapping is somehow similar.